# Changing calculation mode in Excel resets copy mode

Tags: excel

I select a cell and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy. The dashed border appears around the cell and I can now paste somewhere else. But if I change calculation mode (from automatic to manual or vice versa) the copy mode is reset. In other words, the dashed border disappears and I can no longer paste.

Why does this happen? Has this always been the case or is it a recent change by Microsoft?

Comment: This always happens when a macro runs. Would love to know why as well

Comment: Forgot to say you also can't undo after running a macro

Comment: There is no macro running. It is happening in the normal Excel interface.